# GWT: Prevent Javascript minification

Tags: javascript, gwt, minify, smartgwt

In GWT, the javascript that is generated from the GWT compiler is super optimized an unreadable. It would be quite helpful it there is a way to avoid this and obtain human readable javascript code.

Is there a config or any other way to prevent GWT from minifying the generated JavaScript for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 4):

When you compile the GWT project there is an option "Output Style" with the options Obfuscated,Pretty,Detailed. Choosing pretty would do the trick.

Comment: It is not making any effect. Generated javascript is still the same. :(

Comment: Pretty does not obfuscate the javascript. This generated javascript  is not supposed to be human readable. It's super optimized and you're not supposed to work with it. Only with java.